# spring security token request requires authentication

Tags: spring, security, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement Authorization Code Grant Flow of OAuth 2.0. But stuck with the issue of Authentication popup on token request.

Here is my code.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig 
       extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Override
public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("admin").password("abc").roles("ADMIN");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll()
            .and().csrf().disable();
}
```

}

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthServerOAuth2Config 
        extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer
                .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("test")
                .secret("test_secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                .scopes("write");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .approvalStoreDisabled();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    protected AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices() {
        return new InMemoryAuthorizationCodeServices();
    }
}
```

To get token I do the following steps:

1. Using browser go to: 
   http://localhost:9000/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=test&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&scope=write
2. First it redirects me to a Login form, where I enter username and passord: admin abc
3. Then it asks if I allow to provide the permission to my "test" client.
4. It redirects me to "redirect uri": http://localhost:8080?code=XXX
5. Then I copy code and use Google Advanced Rest Client to send Token Request:
   POST on http://localhost:9000/oauth/token?client_id=test&grant_type=authorization_code&code=XXX
   Without any headers. As far as I understand Poster should use Browser cookie.
6. As result on token request I see a popup asking to fill username and password while expecting to get access token in response.

[image: Poster popup]

Please, help me to solve the issue. Should I add some headers to my token request? Or my Authorization Server config is not correct?

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason of the issue by myself just reading others resources of OAuth2 specification.
It it is required to send Authorization on token request with the following value:

```
Authorization: Basic {base64 encode of clientId:clientSecret}
```